# Using methods for the objects in class

Tags: c++, class, methods

How to call methods which I declared in class for my private variables? This code causes Fail: non-declared method At. I want in function Top() to use method At() which I declared earlier. Please, help :)
For Example:

```
class A{
public:
      void At(size_t i){
            Check_i(i);
            return one[i];     
     }
     void Top(){
          return one.At(i);
     }

private:
     vector<int> one;
}
```

Comment: You can call the method `At` directly from within the `Top` method. `std::vector` does not have a method called `At`, which is what `one.At(i)` is attempting to call. There are a number of other errors in the code that you have posted which will cause compilation to fail.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use pointer 'this', void Top(size_t i) {return this->At(i);}